# Java Program error while running scp command with Jsch library via ssh

Tags: java, ssh, file-transfer, scp, jsch

I'm using following java program to copy one folder from my ubuntu laptop to another laptop. I'm basically using below scp command to copy files.

```
sshpass -p mypassword scp root1@192.168.1.2:/home/Email/*  /home/MyFolder/
```

Here
192.168.1.2 is remote machine with ssh enabled.
/home/MyFolder  is the path to my local machine where I want to copy all the files.

Now the problem is I CAN copy folder when i run this individual command in the linux TERMINAL without any problem. But I CANNOT get the folder copied when I pass the same command from the java program given below.  Where am I wrong in this ? Please help me.

I'm getting the following output in my java program when I run the program:

Output

```
Connected
exit-status :6
DONE
```

Here is the complete java program I'm using.

```
import java.io.InputStream;
import com.jcraft.jsch.Channel;
import com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelExec;
import com.jcraft.jsch.JSch;
import com.jcraft.jsch.Session;


public class SSHCommandExecutor {

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String host="192.168.2.12";
    String user="root1";
    String password="mypassword";
    String command1="sshpass -p mypassword scp root1@192.168.1.2:/home/Email/*  /home/MyFolder/";
    try{

        java.util.Properties config = new java.util.Properties(); 
        config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
        JSch jsch = new JSch();
        Session session=jsch.getSession(user, host, 22);
        session.setPassword(password);
        session.setConfig(config);
        session.connect();
        System.out.println("Connected");

        Channel channel=session.openChannel("exec");
        ((ChannelExec)channel).setCommand(command1);
        channel.setInputStream(null);
        ((ChannelExec)channel).setErrStream(System.err);

        InputStream in=channel.getInputStream();
        channel.connect();
        byte[] tmp=new byte[1024];
        while(true){
          while(in.available()>0){
            int i=in.read(tmp, 0, 1024);
            if(i<0)break;
            System.out.print(new String(tmp, 0, i));
          }
          if(channel.isClosed()){
            System.out.println("exit-status: "+channel.getExitStatus());
            break;
          }
          try{Thread.sleep(1000);}catch(Exception ee){}
        }
        channel.disconnect();
        session.disconnect();
        System.out.println("DONE");
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

}
```